# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged vs SelectedItemChanged

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` and a `Label` on my `Form` in the Windows Forms. And I want the label's text to change when the user selects an option in the ComboBox to the string that depends on what item is selected.

What event should I use - SelectedIndexChanged or SelectedItemChanged and why? And let me know if there is other solutions for my problem

Comment: Might want to think about `SelectedValueChanged` also